# Is "lightly" a right word in this sentence?

Tags: single-word-requests, grammaticality

> XXX is a place you can **lightly** keep and share your thoughts.

This is my service's tagline. XXX represents the service name.
I'm not sure *lightly* is the right word in this sentence. I intended that it means 'feel free' or 'feel comfortable'.

Comment: Any particular reason that you have to use *lightly*? *Freely and comfortably* seem to work there.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I think both are good candidates. Can i exchange all these words "without worring", freely, easily, comfortably. I want to know best word.

Comment: @jkim Please bear in mind that SE is not a discussion forum. Wait and see what answers you get [below], and then accept the one which helped most. Also, we don't do proof-reading, so I removed that part of the question as it's off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Lightly" doesn't make much sense at all in that context. I would struggle to interpret what the sentence is trying to convey if it wasn't for your clear explanation. I can think of a whole range of misleading interpretations:

- The thoughts you share are being 'lightly' kept, e.g. not stored on a database for very long
- The content is 'light' on length, e.g you can only share brief thoughts
- The content is 'light' on tone, e.g. you should only share positive, happy thoughts.

You're not aiming for any of those interpretations.

Some alternatives:

- comfortably
- freely
- without worrying (as mentioned by **AdamV**)
- casually
- easily
- openly
- simply

Personally, I prefer 'freely' but it all depends what you are trying to convey.

Try putting some of those suggestions into http://www.thesaurus.com/ for further ideas!

Comment: Thank you for alternatives and suggestions. Those are very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

"I did YYY. but did not do it lightly" is a reasonable sentence. "lightly" is contrasting with the idea of something *weighing heavily* on the mind or conscience.
I don't think most native English readers would understand your tagline without it being explained. So you should not use this turn of phrase and find something that is understood at first reading by native and non-native alike.
Example: "XXX is a place you can keep and share your thoughts *without worrying*"

Comment: Thanks for answer. I think "without worring" is a good suggestion. How about freely or easily or comfortably (as like Rathony commented)